# Getting Instagram, Facebook and/or LinkedIn users out of a list of Twitter users

Tags: python, r, facebook, twitter, instagram

I have a list of Twitter users and I want to check if they have accounts on Instagram, Facebook or LinkedIn.

Is there any way to do it using Python or R code?

Thanks!

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. And is there any way to know if a user of a Twitter account has an Instagram account with just the same username?